# How to Control a 3D Printer Extruder

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, 3d

I am trying to control a 3D Printer Extruder that I got online. I know that for the most part, a person would just plug this in to a circuit board and it would just work. I want to make my own circuit board to control it. I have the [DC12V K-Type 0.4mm Nozzle Extruder Print Head Thermocouple For 3D Printer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K5NDLRQ) from Amazon.com. It obviously runs on 12v but I cant get any more info then that. I know how to control the stepper motor and the fan (assuming it runs on 12v) but as you can see there are 4 wires coming out of the hot end. I assume 2 of them are to a heating element(maybe the fabric ones) and the other 2 go to a thermistor or some sort of temperature sensor. I just don't know how many volts to put into the hot end, how many amps does it consume, and how I can get readings off of the temperature sensor. I want to hopefully do this with an Arduino and I would also assume that some circuit would have to be built in order to get the proper voltage to the hot end and fan. If at all possible could anyone please answer some of these questions and possibly draw me a schematic of what I would need to do in order to achieve my goal? Thank You.[image: The Extruder that I Have]

Comment: Not to sound like a curmudgeon, but what's wrong with existing extruders controller solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You blew it on this one. If your intent was to build the controller from scratch, then you need full data on the extruder. However, the seller clearly states:

> Pls kindly note that the manufacturer doesn't provide any English manual for this item.

However, there are ways to get clues about the hookup, at least. The seller's page says that the temperature sensor is a type-K thermocouple. Try hooking up pairs of wires to a meter with type-K thermocouple capability until you see a reasonable room-temperature indication. Verify that warming/cooling the unit changes the indication accordingly.

Then measure the DC resistance of the other pair of wires to get some idea of the voltage/current values required for the heater. Try applying power to the heater to see what power levels give you what temperatures on the thermocouple.